# Spark - sort by value with a JavaPairRDD

Tags: sorting, apache-spark

Working with `apache spark` using `Java`. I got an `JavaPairRDD<String,Long>` and I want to sort this dataset by its value. However, it seems that there only is `sortByKey` method in it. How could I sort it by the value of `Long` type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Secondary sort' is not supported by Spark yet (See [SPARK-3655](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3655) for details).

As a workaround, you can sort by value by swaping key <-> value and sorting by key as usual.

In Scala would be something like:

```
val kv:RDD[String, Long] = ??? 
// swap key and value
val vk = kv.map(_.swap)
val vkSorted = vk.sortByKey
```

Comment: Is there a similar implementation using Java?

Comment: you have `scala.Tuple2.swap()`, `JavaPairRDD.map()` and `JavaPairRDD.sortByKey()`. All the pieces you need.

Answer (score 7):

dataset.mapToPair(x -> x.swap()).sortByKey(false).mapToPair(x -> x.swap()).take(100)

Comment: Working fine... Can you please explain the code. thanks for the code :)

Comment: @AbhinavRawat https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach5 for the Lambdas, and this is for the RDD interface, where you can find the methods details, good luck :) : https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html

Comment: @JBoy thanks, I can't actually remember when I posted it, but can easily understand the code now.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this using a List, which now has a `sort(Comparator c)` method

`List<Tuple2<String,Long>> touples = new ArrayList<>();
    touples.addAll(myRdd.collect()); //
    touples.sort((Tuple2<String, Long> o1, Tuple2<String, Long> o2) -> o2._2.compareTo(o1._2));`

It is longer than @Atul solution and i dont know if performance wise is better, on an RDD with 500 items shows no difference, i wonder how does it work with a million records RDD.
You can also use `Collections.sort` and pass in the list provided by the `collect` and the lambda based `Comparator`

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Long> sorted = reduce.mapToPair(tuple -> new Tuple2<Long, String>(tuple._2, tuple._1))
                    .sortByKey(false)
                    .mapToPair(tuples -> new Tuple2<>(tuples._2, tuples._1));
```

Swap using mapToPair, then sort, then swap again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).